# When activity comes foreground go to main activity not to top of the stack

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, android-lifecycle

I have 3 activities, then I navigate from A to B and from B to C. The stack are C-B-A (with C on the top). The C Activity have a Runnable that works every interval, and connect to a web service that update the UI. If the Activity C comes to background, is destroyed and then comes to foreground again the task starts with de main Activity A. I want to come back to the C activity. Is possible?

In the emulator works fine but in my smartphone with only this application running, always destory the entire application.. can I do somthing? If I do a service separated from the UI, could improve this?

Edit2: I try this declaration on AndroidManifest

```
    <activity android:name=".ActivityA" android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    
        </intent-filter> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="oauthht" android:host="hattrick"/>
        </intent-filter>          
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityB" android:label="@string/ActivityB"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityC" android:label="@string/ActivityC" 
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Edit2: And the code to call the activities:

In the main Activity A:

```
public void onClickButtonB(View button) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this,ActivityB.class));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the Activity B:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putLong("selectedMatch", matchID);           

 Intent liveIntent = new Intent(); 
 liveIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class));
 liveIntent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(liveIntent);
```

Comment: It does sound like your Activity C could/should be a service that runs in the background.

Comment: Themanatuf that makes zero.sense to me.

Comment: How are you launching your Activities in code? Please include the code. It sounds like you're including flags that mess up the default behavior.

Comment: Please post how you launch activities in the code and also manifest declaration of activity B.

Comment: Thanks! now I put the code, and I put all in the manifest (the activityA was wrong).. maybe the problem is on the intent-filter of the ActivityA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know which was the problem. The application crashes in background but the exception was caught. This restarts the app in background and mislead me. :-S